# angular ui bootstrap popover open programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angularjs-digest

I am trying to open the popover dynamically by setting popover-is-open property to true dynamically from the controller like this:

```
    var el = angular.element(target.id); //popover attached to this element
    el.attr('popover-is-open',true) //setting attribute to true
    $compile(el.contents())($scope) //recompiling
    $scope.$digest();//running digest
```

Here is the html

```
<div id="taskcard-{{task.externalId}}" 
     popover-append-to-body="true" 
     popover-trigger="'none'" 
     popover-is-open="false"
     uib-popover-template="templateurl" 
     popover-title="testing">
          POPOVERS
</div>
```

Now, this doesn't work. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: can you please post full code including `html` here

Comment: @jitender check above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some Boolean flag instead something like  `task.popoverIsOpen` in `popover-is-open` attribute and can set it to `true` or `false` to open/close popover something like

```
 <div id="taskcard-{{task.externalId}}" 
     popover-append-to-body="true" 
     popover-trigger="'none'" 
     popover-is-open="task.popoverIsOpen"
     uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" 
     popover-title="testing">
          POPOVERS
</div>
```

Set `popoverIsOpen` to `true` when you need

```
task.popoverIsOpen=true;
```

[Working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/eQYXvNp4MjVj6lCLJSr8?p=preview)

Comment: can't use it. i have like 100 popovers! can't maintain separate flag for each. And if i keep only one flag, all the popovers will open and close together :)

Comment: you mean to say you are using it inside `ng-repeat` of `tasks` right?

Comment: actually i have a requirement that all only one popover should be open at a time. So in your plunker user can have all the popovers open.

Comment: @beNerd check out update [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BJHJSL2963GnYrH1LDoJ?p=preview)

Comment: there is still a issue: instead of ng-click, I need to use ng-mouseenter and popover should be removed on mouseleave. i tried replacing ng-click with mouseenter but the popover doesn't disappear on mouseleave

Comment: @beNerd in that case you also need to add `ng-mouseleave="togglePopover(task)"` check updated answer also mark it as accepted ans if it works for you

Comment: well that's not exactly the one i was looking for. It closes as soon as you hover the popover. I have devised a solution to this and will post it in a gist. Thanks for your help!